# when there are 2 opamps in a circuit working simultaneously how do we sketch transfer characteristics?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, homework, nodal-analysis, 741-opamp

[image]

could you please help me finding transfer characteristic (v2/v1) of this circuit.

Comment: Where did the circuit come from?

Comment: Looks like homework. Show us what work you've done so far to solve this.

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions here. You need to show us that you have put forth a significant effort yourself, and show us **all** of your work. Then you should ask a **specific** question.

Comment: I've got this V2/V1 = (3 *(2 + 4))/(4*(3 - 4 + 2 )) = -4.5 V/V

Comment: actually I am confused about do they have to operate in same mode at the same time. I mean how do we decide for example if the first op amp operates in linear mode whether the second one in linear or saturation mode?